# Can't add Buttons with their own layouts to another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-include

I need to accomplish the following tasks:

1) each of four buttons is held inside its own Relative or Frame
   layout

2) these four layouts with buttons inside them are added to
   another bigger layout thru `include` 
   tag

3) this bigger layout is to change the IDs and text of these
   buttons

So far I have made the following things:

To accomplish the Task #1, I created *res/layout/big_button_layout.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<my.planner.BigButton
    android:id="@+id/nonameButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To accomplish the Tasks #2 and #3, I created the bigger layout in *res/layout/big_buttons_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<include
    layout="@layout/big_button_layout"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title1"
    />

<include
    layout="@layout/big_button_layout"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title2"
    />

<include
    layout="@layout/big_button_layout"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title3"
    />

<include
    layout="@layout/big_button_layout"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title4"
    />
```

I have two problems:

1) Why are buttons not visible?

2) How do I change IDs and text of the buttons from the bigger layout?

Comment: you cannot change ID of element. You can change text, but from code, not from XML.

Comment: as for visibility - use WRAP_CONTENT in <include> tag for layout_height

Comment: Thanks. So having a button inside its own layout ain't a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Nice time pass

1. I doubt whether you can set text with include tag
2. Even if you can set text this way, you can not set text to relative layout - it doesn't support text attribute.
3. You can not change IDs of buttons this way,